# Fleet Telematics Waypoints Sequence response time

Tags: here-api

I'm doing a request with 12 destinations, and the response time is about 13.6 seconds, I'm thinking this is a lot of time compared to the other API that I used, with same destinations it take 4seconds. There is a way that I can do it faster? It's the only one topic to I consider to get the Pro Plan.

My request is at the endpoint: 
https://wse.api.here.com/2/findsequence.json

And the parameters are:
start=origem;-23.630479,-46.637881&&departure=2015-08-17T07:30:00%2b01:00&destination1=441860;-31.747559,-52.399329;&destination2=443576;-28.256848,-52.456601;&destination3=440063;-6.3661229,-39.308801;&destination4=444208;-19.734489,-45.262761;&destination5=444225;-22.882374,-43.425541;&destination6=444506;-20.191885,-40.270924;&destination7=441313;-22.957170,-43.343008;&destination8=441316;-5.7276168,-35.243387;&destination9=445037;-30.348000,-54.332883;&destination10=444983;-22.882374,-43.425541;before:destination2&destination11=445061;-21.759055,-43.349938;&destination12=445044;-30.348000,-54.332883;&end=pontofinal;-23.630479,-46.637881&mode=fastest;car;traffic:disabled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the new syntax, there is a response time tuning parameter "firstWayPointReach":

http://fleet.cit.api.here.com//2/calculateroute.json
?app_id=xxxxx&app_code=Xxx
&mode=fastest;car;traffic:disabled
&waypoint0=-23.630479,-46.637881
&waypoint1=-31.747559,-52.399329;sort
&waypoint2=-28.256848,-52.456601;sort
&waypoint3=-6.3661229,-39.308801;sort
&waypoint4=-19.734489,-45.262761;sort
&waypoint5=-22.882374,-43.425541;sort
&waypoint6=-20.191885,-40.270924;sort
&waypoint7=-22.957170,-43.343008;sort
&waypoint8=-5.7276168,-35.243387;sort
&waypoint9=-30.348000,-54.332883;sort
&waypoint10=-22.882374,-43.425541;sort;before:2
&waypoint11=-21.759055,-43.349938;sort
&waypoint12=-30.348000,-54.332883;sort
&waypoint13=-23.630479,-46.637881
&algopts=firstWayPointReach0.0

Finds the same result in less time, but still takes a few seconds.